# vue, animation on dynamic component not triggering?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a page like this:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" @click="currentView='create'">Create</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" @click="currentView='how'">How</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" @click="currentView='about'">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" @click="currentView='youtube'">Videos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <keep-alive>
        <component :is="currentView" transition="fade" transition-mode="out-in"></component>
    </keep-alive>
</div>
```

js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Create from '../components/homepage/create.vue';
import How from '../components/homepage/how.vue';
import About from '../components/homepage/about.vue';
import Youtube from '../components/homepage/youtube.vue';
import Navigation from '../components/navigation.vue';

Vue.component('navigation', Navigation)
Vue.component('create', Create)
Vue.component('how', How)
Vue.component('about', About)
Vue.component('youtube', Youtube)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentView: 'create'
    }
})
```

sass:

```
.fade-transition {
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and that code apparently should make the components to have animations when they switch. They do switch however without the animation, why is this happening am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
<keep-alive>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <component :is="currentView"></component>
    </transition>
</keep-alive>
```

Please see if this works. Also, check that the CSS in included.

Comment: hmm that works, how come my way didn't work? apparently that's a valid method //edit it doesn't work exactly if I change css transition to 6s, there is no difference. It is attached

Comment: what happens is, it flashes white and then change the component if I remove transition it doesn't do that. So something is working but not fully

Comment: Because component doesn't have transition-name and transition-mode props (at least I didn't find any mentions of it in documentation). What about changing the timing - there shouldn't be any problems with that. Can you create a snippet?

Comment: changed the timing to 10 seconds still not being applied

Comment: Try adding duration="10s" to transition, like this: <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" duration="10s">